# How to get a json array in a one row in hive, not trying to explode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I think my question is very simple but I am not able to find any specific answers.

I have a JSON like this:

```
{"data": 
   {"updated": "yes",
    "car": [{"type": "fancy", "name": "bmw"}, 
            {"type": "normal", "name": "honda"}]
   }
}
```

I want to put this in a hive table as:

```
updated                                 car
yes        "{"type": "fancy", "name": "bmw"},{"type": "normal", "name": "honda"}"
```

I have used from_json, to_json but can't get it to work. Again, I don't want to break it down into multiple rows based on array elements.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to_json` should work!

```
df.select(col("data.updated").alias("updated"), to_json(col("data.car")).alias("car")).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|updated|car                                                             |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|yes    |[{"name":"bmw","type":"fancy"},{"name":"honda","type":"normal"}]|
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```